# How to schedule a task without using windows service or task Manager in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My tasks are like sending a report in mail.Currently my tasks are scheduled in windows service which is installed in my project server. There are repeated changes in my tasks where i need to install/uninstall my windows service for which i might need to reboot the system and Other applications are hosted in that server if some thing is wrong in my service. any guidance/idea in the design is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: all you need is http://hangfire.io/

Comment: Assuming there is a good reason you can't schedule a repetitive task (BTW, why not? permissions?) then make the service just run another executable you're free to update without restarting Windows...

Comment: If you need to uninstall and reinstall your service or even restart the entire server, you have bigger problems. Fix those problems, and the need to find an alternative for Windows Services should go away.

Comment: Put the details of your tasks into editable configuration (eg config files, a database or something else) and implement a mechanism for the service to update itself (either automatically by watching for changes or manually by calling an update method somehow). Then you don't need to update your service unless it the actually rules on how to schedule need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I write the service to respond to the stop/start cycle properly. Once stopped you should be able to update the executable without uninstalling first.

If that is somehow not possible, and I would like to know the scenario, you could always write your service to perform a web call to a remote service to perform the desired functionality.